# Express Electron Cannot Require Local Js Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron, electron-builder

Before marking as duplicate, I've searched a lot and I couldn't find the answer I need.

I have some issues using express and electron. Everything works fine when I run `npm start` (*start* script in `package.json` is `electron .`). The problem shows up after building electron using `electron-builder`. It builds the project for windows x-64 and makes `.exe` file in the dist folder. Everything look fine until I want to run the executable app. There is this dialog showing up:

[image: Electron Error Dialog]

I did a lot of search and I couldn't find out what is wrong. Actual problem is that somehow electron cannot require local js files after building. I tried both asar true and false during build.

Here is my project tree:

```
 app
 ├── node_modules
 │   └── ...
 ├── Controllers
 │   ├── baseController.js
 │   └── homeController.js
 ├── Database
 │   ├── journals.json
 │   └── users.json
 ├── Models
 │   ├── Journal.js
 │   ├── User.js
 │   └── index.js
 ├── Repository
 │   ├── motor
 │   |   ├── generator.js
 │   |   └── index.js
 │   ├── core
 │   |   └── index.js
 │   ├── init.js
 │   └── index.js
 ├── Views
 │   └── index.html
 ├── www
 │   └── assets
 │       └── images
 │           └── ...
 ├── app.js
 ├── package.json
 ├── package-lock.json
 ├── startup.js
 └── server.js
```

Here is my `app.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const server = require(path.join(__dirname, 'server'));
const port = 7970;
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = electron;
let index;

// App Ready
app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false;
app.on('ready', function () {
    index = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
            nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        },
        frame: true,
        minimizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        fullscreen: false,
        resizable: false,
        movable: true
    });
    index.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join("localhost:" + port),
        protocol: 'http:',
        slashes: true
    }));
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
});
```

Here is `startup.js` where the error actually starts in stack trace:

```js
const path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var controllers = require(path.join(__dirname, '/Controllers/baseController'));

router.get('/', controllers.home.index)

module.exports = router;
```

I've already tried require with relative path like `require("./whatever")`
and it did not differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron is probably not shipping your files with the installation package. Try adding the *extraFiles* field to your `package.json`

So, inside your `package.json`, and inside your `build` field, add this:

```
build:{
    "appId":"your.product.id",
     ...
    "extraFiles":[
        {
            "from":"Controllers",
            "to":"resources/app/Controllers",
            "filter":["**/*"]
        },
        {
            "from":"Database",
            "to":"resources/app/Database",
            "filter":["**/*"]
        },
        {
            "from":"Models",
            "to":"resources/app/Models",
            "filter":["**/*"]
        },
        {
            "from":"Repository",
            "to":"resources/app/Repository",
            "filter":["**/*"]
        },
        {
            "from":"Views",
            "to":"resources/app/Views",
            "filter":["**/*"]
        },
        {/** You can add more if you need*/}
    ]
}
```

Electron, by default, neglects all devDependencies and "new" files when building. The [extraFiles](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extrafiles) field prevents electron-builder from neglecting files that are necessary to your app's execution. It actually ships the files located in the `from` field into the path in `to` field.
The `filter` is used to leave some files using an extension or an inside directory if necessary.

`extraFiles` has the default path as your app's root directory.